# Plane passing through 3 vectors

Tags: vectors

I came across a demo that asks for the following.
Prove that the plane passing for $$\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}$$ has for normal vector a $$\vec{n}=(\vec{u} \times \vec{v}) + (\vec{v} \times \vec{w})+(\vec{u} \times \vec{w})$$

My idea is to make a dot product of each of the vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}$ , with the normal vector, however I do not get any results.
I would appreciate any attempt at guidance.

Comment: Hint: look up the scalar triple product, which represents the volume of a parellelepiped. Note when the volume of a parallelepiped is zero

Comment: I think your formula is wrong. The last term should be $\vec w\times\vec u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ are three points that define a plane. To get the normal, you need two vectors in that plane. You can choose $\vec v-\vec u$ and $\vec w-\vec u$. Then the direction of the normal is given by the cross product:
$$\vec n=(\vec v-\vec u)\times(\vec w-\vec u)\\=\vec v\times \vec w-\vec u\times \vec w-\vec v\times\vec u+\vec u\times \vec u$$
Now using $\vec a\times\vec a=0$ and $\vec a\times\vec b=-\vec b\times\vec a$ you get $$\vec n=\vec u\times\vec v+\vec v\times\vec w+\vec w\times\vec u$$
Note that the last term is opposite of what you have in your problem (I think you have a mistake).

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this question will be more specific: What is $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$?

Sometimes, this means a oriented segment with the origin as the starting point(Some people deliberately confuse oriented segment and vectors for convenience.).

If then, **the plane** is not a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^4$ but a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ that is used to us(this is likely because the cross product appears in the process of solving it), such a plane generally does not exist.

If not, does it mean a point in $\mathbb R^3$(Of course, $\mathbb R^3$ is $\mathbb R$-vector space, this notation is not *illegal*.)? Then, since the plane passing through the three points is unique, you can create a vector equation of the plane you mentioned. This is not difficult.

So, let me ask you again. What is $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$?